# It's fine by me

Tags: idioms, prepositions

"Fine by me" seems like an unusual use of the word 'by'. Is it unique, or are there other cases like this? Is there a special term for this specific pattern?

Answer (score 3):

It is in the sense of "according to" or "with respect to" mentioned in all good dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks -- yes, I see on m-w.com that the least frequent usage given is: in the opinion of / from the point of view of <okay by me>. So that confirms it's unusual, but not whether it's unique, since that example matches mine above. Are there any other cases like this?

Comment: To elaborate: does this usage only occur in this pattern? I could try to say "it's no good by you" or "it's intriguing by the reviewer", but I've never heard the former, and the latter sounds invalid.

Comment: It's not completely unique; *"okay by me" "fine by him", "okay by them",* and so forth, are also used. The *OED* has *"is jake by me"* and *"if that's all right by you"* and specify *"in expressions indicating agreement"*. They don't mention any other similar usages, though.

Comment: @PeterShor thank you; this seems to be the most relevant response with regard to the question. Want to repost as an answer? Ben, according to [this entry on m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by), 6b: according to; 7b: with respect to; and 11: in the opinion of; are each distinct, with this usage being #11, do you concur?